# Orange box on PS3?

Tags: ps3, steam

I understand that you can install and play Orange Box games (HL2, HL2:E1, HL2:E2, Portal, TF2) on the PS3. However, when I go to http://store.steampowered.com/sub/469/, I don't see the PS3 listed.

I'm afraid of buying the game, and then finding out I can't play it on the PS3. Does the PS3 have a version of Steam? Or can I buy on the PC and download it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently games sold on the Steam store have no connection to any titles available for the PS3. [Valve and Sony have partnered](http://www.geek.com/articles/games/valve-is-bringing-steam-to-ps3-20100616/) on bringing Steam functionality to the PS3, but haven't committed in any way regarding making the Steam store available as a distribution platform for the system, and it seems unlikely that it would happen given that it would be a direct competitor to the PSN store.

In short, if you want to play The Orange Box on the PS3 **do not** purchase from Steam, as this will only get you the PC/Mac version; you'll need to find a retail disc in three-space, I'm afraid.

Comment: Another strange thing: EA is no longer making The Orange Box for PS3, so it's becoming scarce.  With the launch of Portal 2 only 4 months away, you'd think Valve would at least put Portal on PSN.